# Automapper error when parsing Enum: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Tags: c#, enums, automapper

I am trying to parse the enum value in automapper and getting the error:
A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression

```
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Sex, opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>
        {
            return !Enum.TryParse(typeof(SexType), src.Sex, out var parsedResult) ? SexType.UNKNOWN : parsedResult;
        }))
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just remove the brackets and return-statment:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Sex, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => !Enum.TryParse(typeof(SexType), src.Sex, out var parsedResult) ? SexType.UNKNOWN : parsedResult));
```